# Astroboy episode where a robot fights other strong robots?

Tags: episode-identification, astroboy

I recall watching an *Astroboy* episode as a child repeatedly because I enjoyed it so much.

It was a two-parter with a robot supposed to be the 'ultimate' robot and he was sent to fight 8 other robots, including Astroboy, to prove he was the ultimate robot.  He had horns like a bull but was a humanoid and at the end of the second episode is defeated.

I remember he successfully defeats one particularly strong robot in the ocean but is severely crippled and Astroboy or Uran helps to activate his distress beacon.

I was wondering what the name of this episode and the robot described was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The episodes referred to are episodes 23 and 24 of the 1982 English series 'The Greatest Robot in the World' parts 1 and 2.

The robot was called [Pluto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto_%28Astro_Boy%29) and was sent created on the orders of a Sultan who wanted the most powerful robot in the world.  [Pluto](https://astroboy.fandom.com/wiki/Pluto) (called 'Bruton' in the English series) is defeated at the end of those two episodes by Bora.  The robot who Pluto only just defeats is called Brando.

Below is an image of Pluto/Bruton

[image: Pluto, purple robot with horns, holding Astronomy in his hand]